# Flash Video wont swipe with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, flash, viewflipper

Hello I've been working on this for a while. I'm using GestureListener and ViewFlipper to swipe between two different WebViews. One webview is a chat and the other is a flash stream. The steam is full screen and it won't leave the screen when I swipe. The chat swipes but it won't return when I swipe back. When I change the orientation I can see the chat underneath. Please help.

The gesture is working, but the video won't move. How can I move it to the back?

```
public class WebViewPager extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {

private FrameLayout holder;
private WebView streamView;
private WebView chatView;
private ViewFlipper flipView;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private String url = "http://www.justin.tv/dbz_hd2/popout";
private String url2 = "http://www.justin.tv/chat/embed?channel=dbz_hd2";
private SimpleGestureFilter filter;
private Animation slideLeft;
private Animation slideRight;

final Activity activity = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    holder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.streamViewHolder);
    streamView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.streamView);
    StreamClientSettings();


    flipView = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.mainFlipper);
    flipView.setDisplayedChild(1);
    this.filter = new SimpleGestureFilter(this, this);
    this.filter.setMode(SimpleGestureFilter.MODE_TRANSPARENT);

    slideLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);
    slideRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate);

    new ManageViews().execute();
}


private class ManageViews extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        chatView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.chatView);
        ChatClientSettings();

        return null;
    }

}


@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    this.filter.onTouchEvent(me);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);    
}


public void StreamClientSettings() {

//      streamView = new WebView(this);
//      streamView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
//              LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    streamView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    streamView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    streamView.setWebViewClient(new StreamClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    streamView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    streamView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    streamView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    streamView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    String s = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";
    streamView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(s);
//      streamView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    streamView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              switch (event.getAction()) {
//              case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//              case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
//                  if (!v.hasFocus()) {
//                      v.requestFocus();
//                  }
//                  break;
//              }
            return false;
        }
    });
    streamView.loadUrl(url);

}

public void ChatClientSettings() {

    //chatView = new WebView(this);
//      chatView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
//              LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    chatView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    chatView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    chatView.setWebViewClient(new StreamClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    chatView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    chatView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    chatView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    chatView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    String s = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0.1)";
    chatView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(s);
    chatView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    chatView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    chatView.loadUrl(url2);

}

private void setStreamView() {

    if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() != 0) {
        flipView.setDisplayedChild(0);
        flipView.setInAnimation(slideRight);
        //flipView.setOutAnimation(slideLeft);
    }

}

private void setChatView() {

    if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() != 1) {
        flipView.setDisplayedChild(1);
        flipView.setInAnimation(slideLeft);
        //flipView.setOutAnimation(slideRight);
    }
}


@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (direction) {

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
        if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
            //flipView.setDisplayedChild(1);
            setChatView();
        }
        break;

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
        if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
            //flipView.setDisplayedChild(0);
            setStreamView();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

My Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/mainFlipper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/streamViewHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@null" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/streamView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <WebView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/chatView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure the gesture is being recognized? I would put a log statement in `onSwipe(int direction)` to be sure. It's possible the full screen view is capturing your gesture events.

Comment: Yeah it's deff working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the flash video player is some kind of parent that can't be controlled by java. By removing the view from a layout holder it give the affect of swiping that works. Took a lot of trial and error but it works!

```
    @Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (direction) {

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:
        if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() == 1) {
            //flipView.setDisplayedChild(1);
            setStreamView();
            holder.addView(streamView);
        }
        break;

    case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT:
        if (flipView.getDisplayedChild() == 0) {
            //flipView.setDisplayedChild(0);
            setChatView();
            holder.removeAllViews();
        }
        break;
    }
```